# c++ porque no puedo crear un objeto con new de una escructura

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**este es el codigo completo**

es compilador de visual studio 2022 me da este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo unico que quiero hacer es crear el objeto en el heap!!!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. COmo sugerencia, el código se comparte como texto para no poner a otros a transcribir para replicar tu problema (y tampoco te vamos a responder con imágenes :P). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No puedes crear una referencia que no apunte a nada, así que para crear un `_idolz` tienes que asignar un obligatoriamente un valor a `name`. Como no declaras un constructor de forma explicita (que es en el que tendrias que iniciar `name`), este se toma como eliminado. En lugar de una referencia recibe una copia, o un puntero, y tu código debería funcionar (o crea un constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tipo referencia (variables declaradas como `tipo&`) en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) necesita apuntar a algo; en otras palabras, no puede existir una referencia que no referencie nada:

```
int i = 0;
int &r = i; // 'r' es una referencia a 'i'.
int &error; // 'error' no referencia a nada, esto no es posible en C++.
```

En tu código tienes un objeto que tiene un miembro referencia:

```
struct _idolz {
    int edad;
    std::string& name; // 'name' es una referencia a cadena.
    _idolz* _idol_next;
};
```

Cuando instancias `_idolz` **DEBES** indicar la cadena a la que hará referencia `_idolz::name`:

```
std::string cadena;
_idolz a{0, cadena, nullptr}; // Correcto, 'a::nombre' apunta a 'cadena'.
_idolz b; // Error, 'b::nombre' no apunta a nada.
```

Dado que es **IMPOSIBLE** instanciar un `_idolz` sin argumentos de construcción (necesitas al menos indicar dónde debe apuntar `_idolz::name`) el compilador elimina el constructor predeterminado (el constructor que no recibe argumentos), de ahí tu error:

> no se puede hacer referencia al constructor predeterminado de "_idolz": **es una función eliminada**

Muy probablemente lo que en realidad querías es esto:

```
struct _idolz {
    int edad;
    std::string name; // 'name' es una INSTANCIA de cadena.
    _idolz* _idol_next;
};
```